# Why was this thread closed?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I have been referred here by @jokerdino.

I started [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383880/suspend-doesnt-work-on-my-laptop-hp-dv4t?noredirect=1#comment493417_383880) about my problems with getting my laptop to sleep.  The thread was closed after a few days.  Initially the reason provided was problems with the development branch of Ubuntu.  The thread is concerning 13.10 so I was confused about that; as best I can tell 13.10 is the current stable branch.

The second reason provided is that this is a bug.  If that's the case, that's very useful information.  A simple response of "this is a bug for reason X Y and Z and cannot be addressed by you the user at this time" would have been really good information (and I would have accepted it as the correct answer).

Closing the thread doens't seem to do any good, and is very frustrating for me as a user.  Maybe @jokerdino thinks it's a bug, but user John_smith has discovered that if you change line 55 of whatever.config the problem goes away.

You can read the full history of the discussion at the thread.

I would like to talk to the people who closed the thread to get clarification. If I am misunderstanding something I am wide open to being educated.  If the problem I'm facing is a bug, I would like to read a little bit about why and accept that as an answer. (This will help me, the two users who have bookmarked the thread, and anyone else who comes across it via google), not have the thread be shut down like I did something wrong (and without giving me any clear answer).

Finally, if we don't know for certain that it's a bug, the thread really ought to be re-opened so maybe I and the other users facing this problem can get some help.

Comment: I would also like permission to repost the thread. That one is nuked from all the meta discussion.  But it's a valid question that should be here for anyone to answer.  If you don't want to answer it, that's fine.  But please allow the discussion to take place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The looks like a legit question to me, I've voted to reopen!

Sometimes with power management it's hard to tell if it's a config issue or a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

> Maybe @jokerdino thinks it's a bug

Not only jokerdino, the users dobey, Braiam, Alvar, Eric Carvalho, Glutanimate thinks the same too.

> Closing the thread doens't seem to do any good, and is very frustrating for me as a user.

Yeah, but really, this is not the place to solve bugs with Ubuntu, for that is Launchpad. It's said in the help page too:

> This is not the right place for:
>
> - Linux Mint, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04) and other Linux distributions (try our friends at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange).
> - **Bug reports (How do I submit a bug?).**
> - Issues with the next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1) (More information about Alpha and Beta release issues).
> - Shopping Recommendations
> - Support of versions for Ubuntu releases past "End of Life" (EOL)

Stack Exchange (ergo Ask Ubuntu) is for questions that has 1 valid answer and that that answer will be still valid for the years to come. Bugs and workarounds are just valid until the issue is fixed by developers, hence here's not the right place to solve them.

> Initially the reason provided was problems with the development branch of Ubuntu. The thread is concerning 13.10 so

No, the reason was because it was a bug. The close reason has both:

1. Problems with the Development release. (most of these are bugs and need to be ironed out)
2. Bug reports (that needs to be addressed by developers in Launchpad)

> I would also like permission to repost the thread.

**PLEASE DON'T!** It's likely that will get closed again as bug. With enough Downvotes, close and deleted questions you will hit the Question Quality Ban. It will prevent you from asking more questions until you fix the problems with your previously closed/downvoted questions.

> Finally, if we don't know for certain that it's a bug, the thread really ought to be re-opened so maybe I and the other users facing this problem can get some help.

Problems with Suspencion, power off, power management, etc. are normally problems with the code somewhere in the Kernel (or the GUI for what matters) hence needs to be addressed by developers not here; also you said in your question that **you tried most of the "common solutions" and it didn't work, hence there's a bug.**

Comment: That's some useful information reasoning. I wish you had posted it in the discussion thread for me to review.  If you had (rather than voting to simply close the thread with no explanation) I would have been grateful rather than frustrated. 

I also don't know that you're right.  You used phrasing like "Problems [like this] _are normally_ problems with..".  Well maybe this isn't the normal case.  Maybe @John_Doe has the solution that will fix my problem and now he can't post it.  Or maybe you're right, and the other posters who had a similar problem would have benefited from reading this.

Comment: In either case, closing the thread doesn't appear to do any good.  It inhibits the possibility of an answer coming forward and it prevented me (without doing a ton of additional communication) from understanding that the issue is probably a bug.

Comment: @JoshuaD comments are not meant for discussion about the question, but to inquire the poster more information/clarification. And the explanation was in the same close reason and dobey was nice enough to tell why was he voting to close the qeustion.

Comment: @JoshuaD if it has the possibility of being a bug, you should report it in LaunchPad then the big guys there will told you either it is indeed a bug or you are just doing things wrong, and your question in particular smells a bug however I see it.

Comment: "StackExchange (ergo AskUbuntu) is for questions that has 1 valid answer and that that answer will be still valid for the years to come. [...] here's not the right place to solve them." It really seems like you should have submitted "This is a bug for reasons X and Z. The proper venue to resolve this is <link>" as an answer to the question. I would have said thank you, I would have upvoted and accepted your answer, other users could have learned from it, and the thread would be open for @JohnSmith to come forward and say "No, it's not a bug! Edit line 55 of whatever.config! It worked for me!"

Comment: "StackExchange (ergo AskUbuntu) is for questions that has 1 valid answer and that that answer will be still valid for the years to come. [...] here's not the right place to solve them." is actually incorrect, the Stack Exchange system actively encourages multiple answers offering different methods of completing the same task so that the best method as determined by the community is upvoted to the top. This is [clearly shown on the about page](http://askubuntu.com/about) for every Stack Exchange site. Bugs are still off topic though regardless.

Comment: Anyway, I think you guys made the wrong call here for the reasons I outlined in my previous comment.Guessing that something is a bug _is_ an answer (which can be falsified by another poster).  Treating it like that seems like the better method to me.  As you are the moderators here, please consider it. Especially since no one has said "I am 100% certain this is a bug" In either case, thank you for your assistance,and thank you for what you do to keep this place running.I disagree with this decision, but I am sure that your jobs aren't easy(and thankless to boot)so thank you for doing your best

Comment: @JoshuaD OK, let me put this clear. Will we spend our time trying to figure out why is or not is a bug instead of you reporting a bug and then comming back with a definitive fix for all the people that use Ubuntu? I'm sure that most of AU users and people that answers questions will say no.

Comment: @JoshuaD We live by the rule, abide by the rules, and **do not bend the rules**. The rules says that your question is about a bug, henceforth your question is Offtopic.

Comment: @Braiam:I am really confused with what you have said.Where in the rules does it say that any power-related issue is a bug? Where is the rules does it say that "problems of nature X are bugs"? It seems possible to me that this is a configuration issue. I tend to believe you that it's a bug, but I think it would be best to leave the possibility open that it's not, unless you are 100% sure. Are you 100% sure? If so, how? Either way, I have made my case. I think you are handling this issue incorrectly and for the sake of the boards I have asked you to reconsider.It's your choice. Thank you again.